# Random/non-constant default value for model field?

Tags: django

I've got a model that looks something like this

```
class SecretKey(Model):
    user = ForeignKey('User', related_name='secret_keys')
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    key = CharField(max_length=16, default=randstr(length=16))
    purpose = PositiveIntegerField(choices=SecretKeyPurposes)
    expiry_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=7), null=True, blank=True)
```

You'll notice that the default value for `key` is a random 16-character string. Problem is, I think this value is getting cached and being used several times in a row. Is there any way I can get a different string every time? (I don't care about uniqueness/collisions)

Comment: you should apply Daniel's answer to the `expiry_date`, too. You won't get the desired result with the current code.

Comment: @[iquadrat: Yeah... I noticed that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the default will only be set when the Model metaclass is initialized, not when you create a new instance of SecretKey.

A solution is to make the default value a [callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default), in which case the function will be called each time a new instance is created.

```
def my_random_key():
    return randstr(16)

class SecretKey(Model):
    key = CharField(max_length=16, default=my_random_key)
```

You could, of course, also set the value in the model's `__init__` function, but callables are cleaner and will still work with standard syntax like `model = SecretKey(key='blah')`.

Comment: I could just slap a `lambda:` in front of it to make it callable, couldn't I?

Comment: yeah, I thought of that after i posted :)

Comment: btw, I would love to use `F()` instances as default values. I should quit being lazy and go fill a ticket on http://code.djangoproject.com ...someday

Comment: Is it possible to pass arguments to callables?

Comment: @MarcoFrattallone no. the closest you could come to that is to define your model over a closure.