# Django request.GET to display value of form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-sessions

Is there a way that i can access the values in my form fields before submitting the form.

I need to store the value of one of my fields in request.session[] so as to access it later ( in the same view). I tried doing it using request.GET but it always none.

```
request.GET.get('name')
```

where **name** is the field in a model.

**Update**

I want to store the value of the form field which is random value generated every time the form is displayed. My models.py contains a random() method which is the default value of the field.

I want to store the field value in sessions, so that i can get the same field value after i return to the page after navigating a few more pages from that page

This is what i was doing:

[Django request.session does not resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240316/django-request-session-does-not-resolve)

Comment: Try `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: Hi,
Maybe you should pose the question in a different way.
You are saying : "Is there a way that i can access the values in my form fields before submitting the form." but the only way to do that is via Client Side Javascript, as you are not sending anything to the server yet. Please clarify

Comment: I think what you're looking for is just request.GET['name']

Comment: @MauroRocco Yes, i need to be able to access the value of the name field when it is displayed. I need to store that value in sessions. So i thought request.GET could be one way of getting the value. Isn't that correct ?

Comment: The name field, is filled by the user or is coming from DB ?
You want to put in the session after the clicking the button SUBMIT or BEFORE ? Explain the real scenario if you can.

Comment: @MauroRocco I updated the question..with some more details...basically i need to store it in sessions before clicking on submit and the value is generated randomly every time the form is displayed. Hope this helps! I have also posted a link to the question in detail and what i was doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all careful when using random in models:

[Random/non-constant default value for model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535031/random-non-constant-default-value-for-model-field)

Once this is clear I suppose you initialise the form in the view, is there that you need to access the form and get the value for put it in session.
For example

```
form = MyModelForm();
request.session['your_session_key'] = form.data['field_name']
```

As far as I understand in some cases you want to set this value in the form from the session instead, for do that you can use the initial data as described here.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Hope this helps

Comment: i have already been using the callable for the default field as you mentioned in the link. And also been using the initial methods to give it the value from the sessions. But the way you mentioned is not correct. I have edited your answer to reflect the new changes. Thanks!

Comment: But i am getting a problem when the form is being displayed with a new random value. When i debug i get a random value in the session, but when the form is displayed it displays with a different value...i guess this i because it is going to that view again. Can you please check the link i have specified in my question. It is the code that i am using for my model.

Comment: I think this is another question than. Post it as a new question including your code. And post a link in the comment

Comment: here is the link to the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323464/django-random-value-issue-with-sessions